# vs2005 - Switching between design and source mode get stuck

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I dont know if anyone else has had this problem. I'm using VS2005 working on a C# website.
The problem is on the .aspx page, when I click on the "Design" option two things happen.
It does not switch to design mode. I see only source. But I the problem is that the source mode gets stuck and uneditable.
Second thing is that I cannot switch back to source mode and hence am stuck only in that non-editable mode.
I tried to Reset my settings, but that hasnt helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: using any 3rd party controls - even if not for webforms?

Comment: Does the aspx in question use any custom UserControls?  I've seen these hang VS2005 when switching to Design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try running visual studio in safemode. Launches Visual Studio in safe mode, loading only the default environment and services, and shipped versions of third party packages.

Try the below command in Start-> Run

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: can you explain a little more how this will help? I'm guessing its like safemode of windows OS.